# Meteor update multiple items on model

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to insert a sub document and update a few properties on a collection all at once like so:

```
    Collection.update(t._id, {$push: {messages: message}, text: textVar});
```

But in doing so receive this message: `Exception in callback of async function: Error: Update parameter cannot have both modifier and non-modifier fields`.

Is there a way to insert and update at the same time? If not, what's the best way to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you need a `$set` for your second key:

```
Collection.update(t._id, {$push: {messages: message}, $set: {text: textVar}});
```